# DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a property with the name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add a read-only property to a dropdown list but getting the following error: "DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a property with the name."

Here is the dropdown code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgvAcademicYear" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsYearsRow"
    Width="150px" ValidationGroup="Add New" DataTextField="AcademicYearDisplay" DataValueField="AcademicYear"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AcademicYear") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsYearsRow" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetCurrentYearsWithDefault"
    TypeName="BLLYears" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="30" Name="yearsBack" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="3" Name="yearsForward" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="defaultYear" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfAcademicYear" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" Name="includeYear" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here is the source of the dropdown code:

```
public List<ListItem> GetCurrentYearsWithDefault(int yearsForward, int defaultYear)
{
    int currentYear = new BLLSchoolInfo().GetCurrentAcademicYear(Campus.AppCode.BusinessLayer.Scheduling.BLLScheduling.SchoolId);
    int yearsBack = 0;
    if (yearsForward <= 0 || yearsForward > 50) yearsForward = 5;

    List<ListItem> ret = new List<ListItem>();
    if (currentYear > 20002001)
        for (int i = currentYear + (10001 * yearsForward); i >= currentYear - (10001 * yearsBack); i -= 10001)
            if (i != currentYear)
                ret.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString().Insert(4, "/"), i.ToString()));

    if (defaultYear > 0 && ret.Find(x => x.Value == defaultYear.ToString()) == null)
        ret.Insert(0, new ListItem(defaultYear.ToString().Insert(4, "/"), defaultYear.ToString()));
    else
        ret.Insert(0, new ListItem(currentYear.ToString().Insert(4, "/"), currentYear.ToString()));

    return ret;
}
```

And here is the read-only property code:

```
public int AcademicYear { get; set; }
public string AcademicYearDisplay
{
    get { return string.Format("{0}/{1}", AcademicYear / 10000, AcademicYear % 10000); }
}
```

The code runs fine when 'DataTextField = "Text" DataValueField = "Value"', but when I change those to "AcademicYearDisplay" and "AcademicYear", I get the error.

Here is the full error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'AcademicYearDisplay'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'AcademicYearDisplay'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'AcademicYearDisplay'.]
   System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName) +2843958
   System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName, String format) +11
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable dataSource) +347
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +290
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +185
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +17
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +185
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +17
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3721
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +26
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883
```

I posted this earlier in the day but am reposting it for more visibility. If I need to give more information, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding a list of `ListItems` to `ddlgvAcademicYear`.
Because those are already the type of items required for a DropDownList, you don't need to specify `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. Those values are already present in the `ListItem` itself. And because the List you are binding it of type `ListItem` it does not contain the properties `AcademicYearDisplay` and `AcademicYear` anyway.

Use it like this.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgvAcademicYear" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsYearsRow"
Width="150px" ValidationGroup="Add New" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AcademicYear") %>'>
```

The way you are binding is needed when you use a table from a database or a list of classes. Those are converted to `ListItems` but there you do need to specify which column/property should become the Text and Value properties of the ListItem.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. Thank you @VDWWD for the explanation. 
One more question, why do I not get an error when I put AcademicYearDisplay and AcademicYear on a label?

`<ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAcademicYear" runat="server" Text='<%# PDConvert.ToAcademicYearFormatted(Eval("AcademicYear")) %>' DataTextField ="AcademicYearDisplay" DataValueField="AcademicYear"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>`

Comment: Because they exist in the entire context of the code behind and are available on the .aspx page. They are not confined to a method.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I will mark this as the correct answer. @VDWWD